# How to get the username to the next activity and show HELLO "USER" with a textview

Tags: android, button, textview

So i need to change activity clicking a button and show the name inserted in the Edittext but seems im not able to get it done . Can someone help me please?

```
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.btn_Saludar);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActivity2();

        }
    });
}

public void openActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

intent.putExtra("name",editext.getText());

in Activity2 --> getIntent().getStringExtra("name);